# Are there any hindu texts on Machiavellian ways one should know ? Or on how to handle people of different kinds

Tags: scripture

Maybe Arthshastra as an ancient text fits the description,But I am looking specifically for hindu texts on such subject or related to it .

Comment: You don't consider Arthashastra a Hindu text?

Comment: It incorporates hindu philosophy only ..So i do consider it a hindu text ..I meant something more ancient and rooted in vedas Puranas ..Arthashastra was more in context of ruling over kingdom..I wanted something which everyone can apply .

Answer (score 1):

Refer Vidura Neeti and  Anusasanika Parva of Mahabharata . Artha Shastra is simply a compilation of ancient texts on Rajaneeti and Rashtraneeti and Kutaneeti

Comment: It would be more useful if some details about the text is added or explained.